# Powershell: Writing string with escaped characters to file

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have a project where I'm trying to dynamically prepare a Powershell script, then write it out to a file for later execution.

Here's a minimal example of the issue:

```
# The string that I want to write out, having most special characters
$_output_str = "~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'`"``;!"

# Write it out directly
Write-Output "$_output_str"
```

This is putting a string with escaped special characters into a variable, then writing the value of that variable out to stdout. It works as expected:

```
~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'"`;!
```

Now, let's try storing that command in a file for later execution.

```
# The string that I want to write out, having most special characters
$_output_str = "~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'`"``;!"

# Turn it into a string command
$_cmd = "Write-Output `"$_output_str`""

# Write the command out to a file
"$_cmd" | Out-File "execution.ps1"
```

And now let's try executing that file:

```
powershell.exe .\execution.ps1
```

This throws an error:

```
At C:\{MYPATH}\execution.ps1:1 char:43
+ Write-Output "~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'"`;!"
+                                           ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

OK, so let's look at the content that was written to the file. This is what `execution.ps1` contains:

```
Write-Output "~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'"`;!"
```

Notice that the `"` and the backtick near the end of the string are no longer escaped. So for some reason, when creating the `$_cmd` string, it got rid of my escape sequences.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Use single-quoted here-string for the value so it doesn't get expanded.

```
$_output_str = @'
~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'"`;!
'@
```

You can also use regular single-quoted strings but keep in mind that you'll have to double any single-quote part of the string.

```
# The single quote is escaped by doubling it, meaning the final 
# representation will be slightly different
$_output_str = '~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,''"`;!'
# Actual value (the two '' were escaped into a single ')
#              '~@#$%&*()-_=+{}[]<>?/.,'"`;!'
```

It is still better than double-quoted strings in any cases.

When you use a double-quoted strings, everything that can get evaluated get evaluated. Your backticks serves to escape the character right after but they are not part of the final representation of the string.

> **Double-quoted strings**
>
> A string enclosed in double quotation marks is an expandable string.
> Variable names preceded by a dollar sign ($) are replaced with the
> variable's value before the string is passed to the command for
> processing.
>
> ...
>
> expressions are evaluated, and the result is inserted in the string.

I recommend you take a look at the official documentation for more information. [About_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)